# Error while installing a package from software-center: Package dependencies cannot be resolved

Tags: dependencies, ubuntu-12.04

I was trying to install Texmaker (latex development environment) from Ubuntu software centre.
But I encountered the following error. I also receive the same error while trying to install many other packages.

> Package dependencies cannot be resolved
>
> This error could be caused by required additional software packages
>   which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a
>   conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be
>   installed at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this way:

1. In a Terminal window, type:

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:texlive-backports/ppa
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
2. Close the Terminal and relaunch Ubuntu Software Centre.